# How to derive state from URL, but also update the query-params whenever state changes in Next.JS?

Tags: reactjs, url, react-hooks, next.js, url-parameters

Beginner here, but finding this quite tricky. So some help would be appreciated!

I want to have users filter through some options. Those filters should be reflected in the URL. e.g. : `http://localhost:3000/items?counter=1`

Now when a user visits `http://localhost:3000/items?counter=2` I want that to be reflected in state & put it in state. If the same user then changes the state somehow, I want that to be reflected in the url. I do know how to do both things.

But I feel I am running into an infinite loop here:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        router.push(`/items?counter=${counter}`, undefined, { shallow: true })
    }, [counter])

    useEffect(() => {
        setCounter(parseInt(router.query.counter))
    }, [router.query.counter])
```

How would I best derive my state from my query params but also always shallow-update the query params every time state changes?

Answer (score 6):

Always update only one of them, and update the other by listening to the changes of the first. Since the state is always derived from the query, I would update the state via `useEffect`, and always change the query directly.

This means that you don't update the state directly. Whenever you want to update the state, you need to update the query:

```
const updateCounterQuery = currentCounter => router.push(`/items?counter=${currentCounter}`, undefined, { shallow: true })

useEffect(() => {
  setCounter(parseInt(router.query.counter))
}, [router.query.counter])
```

However, why do you even need a state in this case? Always use the value that you get from the query:

```
const updateCounterQuery = counter => router.push(`/items?counter=${counter }`, undefined, { shallow: true })

const counter = +router.query.counter
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The last code snippet you posted, would I be doing this in a useeffect? Also: I wouldn't do this with shallow routing, right? Because then my component wouldn't re-render? Or am I not getting something?

Comment: No. You don't need `useEffect`. The component re-renders because `useRouter()` triggers a render, and you get a new router object. Shallow routing doesn't prevent rerender, so it would work. The only thing this code does is assigning a const.

Answer (score 5):

For more complex use cases where multiple query strings (e.g. `?counter=2&filter=true`) or simultaneous updates (e.g. `?latitude=47.367&longitude=8.543`) are required, it usually makes sense to abstract the logic to a hook.

Libraries like [next-usequerystate](https://github.com/47ng/next-usequerystate#usage) solve exactly this use case. Guides and examples like [this](https://dev.to/jeffsalive/solving-the-challenge-of-state-persistence-in-nextjs-effortless-state-management-with-query-parameters-4a6p) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73155416/8929855) are good entrypoints for custom developments.